# How to create a database or role in pgAdmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I want to create a database in pgAdmin4 but a corresponding item in the menu is grayed out.

I also tried to create a role, thinking that I might be lacking permissions to create database in first place, but it is also grayed out.

[image]

When pgAdmin4 loads it asks for master password, which I enter. What else am I expected to do?

Comment: Maybe you are not logged in with the superuser account. What happens if you run `create role` manually?

Comment: You mean in pgAdmin4? How do I log in with superuser account there? The only thing it prompts for is master user password.

I actually ended up going and creating DB from CLI.

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin so I have no idea what a "master user" is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me if the user I am logged in as has either the superuser attribute, or the createrole and/or createdb attribute.

When you create a server (probably a poor wording, you are't initializing a server, but connecting to an existing one), pgAdmin4 definitely asks you for more information than just the master password.  Like what user you want to connect as.

If you want to connect as different users at different times, you need to "create server..." for each one.